# Why in jsp jsp:useBean "scope" attribute has proposals?but c:set "scope" attribute don't has proposals?

Tags: jsp, usebean

Why in jsp `jsp:useBean` "scope" attribute has proposals?

[image]

but `c:set` "scope" attribute don't has proposals?

[image]

Comment: Because your (unknown) IDE isn't as good as it could be?

Comment: My IDE is eclipse

Comment: It could be because there are two sets of semantics for c:set.